# Is $∇g(x)g(x)^T$ equal to $∇g(x)∇g(x)^T$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I am going through a proof which includes the following lines:

$\nabla g(x^k) \big(g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k)^T(x^{k+1}-x^k)\big) = 0$

$\nabla g(x^k) g(x^k) + \nabla g(x^k) g(x^k)^T(x^{k+1}-x^k)\big) = 0$

It's not quite clear to me why for the second term it says:

$\nabla g(x^k) g(x^k)^T$
and not $\nabla g(x^k)\nabla g(x^k)^T$

Is there some kind of identity which can be used here?

Comment: Typo?           (some other letters)

Comment: Its either a typo, someone forget a $\nabla$. But without additional context, this statement is wrong. Just think of the "dimension" of the objects. The second equations is vector + a scalar value.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the replies, it is in fact a typo